# Forbid reviving dead peers in Squid

Tags: load-balancing, squid, timeout, http-proxy

How, I'm using Squid v3.3.8 and I need to create HTTP rotating proxy server to send all requests through set of predefined proxies (I'm automatically updating squid config to update set of working proxies).

My output proxies are not fast and reliable, so I don't want for squid to wait if some of them don't respond fast, I better hope that other are better and never go back to problematic ones.

So this is how my config looks like

```
# Basic configuration
visible_hostname squid_1
unique_hostname squid_1

http_port 3130
pid_filename /home/vagrant/projects/squid_1.pid

dns_v4_first on

peer_connect_timeout 3 seconds
dead_peer_timeout 3 seconds

server_persistent_connections off

http_access allow all

# Proxies list
cache_peer PROXY_HOST parent PROXY_PORT 0 connect-fail-limit=1 round-robin no-query name=node2447551878 login=login2447551878:PASSWORD
cache_peer PROXY_HOST parent PROXY_PORT 0 connect-fail-limit=1 round-robin no-query name=node3119927090 login=login3119927090:PASSWORD
cache_peer PROXY_HOST parent PROXY_PORT 0 connect-fail-limit=1 round-robin no-query name=node4682855833 login=login4682855833:PASSWORD
cache_peer PROXY_HOST parent PROXY_PORT 0 connect-fail-limit=1 round-robin no-query name=node9428960235 login=login9428960235:PASSWORD
cache_peer PROXY_HOST parent PROXY_PORT 0 connect-fail-limit=1 round-robin no-query name=node3796185266 login=login3796185266:PASSWORD

never_direct allow all
```

And this is what I see in **cache.log**

```
2016/04/20 15:28:49 kid1| TCP connection PROXY_HOST/PROXY_PORT failed
2016/04/20 15:28:49 kid1| Detected DEAD Parent: node3796185266
2016/04/20 15:28:49 kid1| Detected REVIVED Parent: node3796185266
2016/04/20 15:28:53 kid1| TCP connection PROXY_HOST/PROXY_PORT failed
2016/04/20 15:28:53 kid1| Detected DEAD Parent: node3796185266
2016/04/20 15:28:53 kid1| Detected REVIVED Parent: node3796185266
2016/04/20 15:28:57 kid1| TCP connection PROXY_HOST/PROXY_PORT failed
2016/04/20 15:28:57 kid1| Detected DEAD Parent: node3796185266
2016/04/20 15:28:57 kid1| Detected REVIVED Parent: node3796185266
2016/04/20 15:29:06 kid1| TCP connection PROXY_HOST/PROXY_PORT failed
2016/04/20 15:29:06 kid1| Detected DEAD Parent: node9428960235
2016/04/20 15:29:06 kid1| Detected REVIVED Parent: node9428960235
2016/04/20 15:29:10 kid1| TCP connection PROXY_HOST/PROXY_PORT failed
2016/04/20 15:29:10 kid1| Detected DEAD Parent: node3796185266
2016/04/20 15:29:10 kid1| Detected REVIVED Parent: node3796185266
2016/04/20 15:29:14 kid1| TCP connection PROXY_HOST/PROXY_PORT failed
2016/04/20 15:29:14 kid1| Detected DEAD Parent: node3796185266
2016/04/20 15:29:14 kid1| Detected REVIVED Parent: node3796185266
```

The problem is that I don't want my DEAD parents to be revived ever (yup, sounds weird).

And also I'm not really sure about how squid detects if my peer is down. I disabled **ICP queries** for every peer by setting `no-query` option and provided port 0, but `dead_peer_timeout` is still thinks my peers are dead after timeout, despite it is using **ICP** [according to the docs](http://www.squid-cache.org/Versions/v3/3.3/cfgman/dead_peer_timeout.html).

**UPDATE**: Added `squid -v` output:

```
Squid Cache: Version 3.3.8
Ubuntu
configure options:  '--build=x86_64-linux-gnu' '--prefix=/usr' '--includedir=${prefix}/include' '--mandir=${prefix}/share/man' '--infodir=${prefix}/share/info' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--localstatedir=/var' '--libexecdir=${prefix}/lib/squid3' '--srcdir=.' '--disable-maintainer-mode' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--disable-silent-rules' '--datadir=/usr/share/squid3' '--sysconfdir=/etc/squid3' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--enable-inline' '--enable-async-io=8' '--enable-storeio=ufs,aufs,diskd,rock' '--enable-removal-policies=lru,heap' '--enable-delay-pools' '--enable-cache-digests' '--enable-underscores' '--enable-icap-client' '--enable-follow-x-forwarded-for' '--enable-auth-basic=DB,fake,getpwnam,LDAP,MSNT,MSNT-multi-domain,NCSA,NIS,PAM,POP3,RADIUS,SASL,SMB' '--enable-auth-digest=file,LDAP' '--enable-auth-negotiate=kerberos,wrapper' '--enable-auth-ntlm=fake,smb_lm' '--enable-external-acl-helpers=file_userip,kerberos_ldap_group,LDAP_group,session,SQL_session,unix_group,wbinfo_group' '--enable-url-rewrite-helpers=fake' '--enable-eui' '--enable-esi' '--enable-icmp' '--enable-zph-qos' '--enable-ecap' '--disable-translation' '--with-swapdir=/var/spool/squid3' '--with-logdir=/var/log/squid3' '--with-pidfile=/var/run/squid3.pid' '--with-filedescriptors=65536' '--with-large-files' '--with-default-user=proxy' '--enable-linux-netfilter' 'build_alias=x86_64-linux-gnu' 'CFLAGS=-g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' 'CPPFLAGS=-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' 'CXXFLAGS=-g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security'
```

Comment: Try adding dead_peer_timeout to 1, and possibly remove the no-query from your cache_peer directive.